# How to write the date (April 17, 2015) in Russian?

Tags: перевод

How would April 17, 2015 be written in Russian, or 4.17.2015?

Answer (score 12):

April 17, 2015 => 17 апреля 2015 г.

4.17.2015 => 17.04.2015

http://www.gramota.ru/spravka/letters/?rub=data

Comment: This is not just a Russian convention, but is used throughout Europe (and in fact most, but not all, of the world outside of North America).

Answer (score 3):

Based on your [additional question](https://russian.stackexchange.com/q/9091/551), there is a special (old-fashioned) way of writting dates that is currently used [on a tombstones and railroad equipment](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B0). For instance, here's how May, 4 2006 will look like:

[image: May, 4 2006].

So, in case of April 17, 2015 it will look like:

```
    17 
 20 -- 15 
    IV
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to be absolutely strict and specific, here is the direct link to CLDR, which specifies the date/time format for Russian locale: http://st.unicode.org/cldr-apps/v#/ru/Generic/