# How to write out the date in russian for a tattoo

Tags: выбор-слова, числительные, орфография

How to write April seventeenth two thousand fifteen in Russian, im trying to figure out a interesting way to get a tattoo of the date my grandmother died

Comment: Answered in your [previous question](http://russian.stackexchange.com/q/9013/551). By the way, you can edit it in order to add more details.

Answer (score 0):

Цифрами можно написать 17.04.2015

Answer (score 0):

In Russian, the date is usually written in the DD.MM.YYYY format, separated by the point, for example 07.07.2015 or 09.05.1945 (the latter means May 9th, not September 5th - day is written first).